# A WebGL intelligent IDE/Environment/Parser

Tags: debugging, ide, intellisense, webgl

Is there an WebGL intelligent IDE/Environment/Parser (... compiler, interpreter ...) that would go through the code and analyze it?

The analysis that I am thinking about is debugging, code interpretation, intellisense...

I know there are some extensions for VS that allow Java Script parsing, but what are your experiences and advices for the best setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you need free one. You can use NetBeans. It can handle pretty well with JavaScript, so it should with WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging WebGL I recommend WebGL Inspector Chrome extension (http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/). It allows you to log all the WebGL calls, see the current state of GL, look at all the buffers (including vertex buffer visualization), shaders, textures, etc. I found it helpful identifying problems with my WebGL code countless times.

For debugging Javascript, you can either go for a full IDE (WebStorm, VS) and use their debugger, or just let Chrome Devtools handle it. I prefer the latter option, because it feels a bit snappier and more 'solid' for me.

Also, Visual Studio Code (their new little IDE based on Atom) has some very nice Javascript Intellisense and includes a debugger. Might be a good idea to check it out.